# Reference messed up by pickling in Python

Tags: python, reference, pickle

I made two references to the same list in python

```
x = y = []
```

And then I pickled them into a text file with `pickle.dump`, but when I loaded them again with `pickle.load`, they became two different lists with different memory address. What can I do to keep the reference relationship during pickling?

Comment: Are you doing `x = y = pickle.load(file)`? I would expect them to point to the same list in that case.

Comment: When you serialize a list (or any object), you make a copy of it. You have written two copies of the same list to a file, but how is Python supposed to know, on reading, that they were once the same list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pickle `x` and `y` as two separate lists, they will not share a reference when you unpickle them, irrespective of whether they did beforehand; *objects*, not *references*, are pickled:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> x = y = [1, 2]
>>> with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(x, f)
    pickle.dump(y, f)


>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
    x = pickle.load(f)
    y = pickle.load(f)


>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False
```

If you want two names to share references after you `load` them back in, you could `pickle` a container:

```
>>> x = y = [1, 2]
>>> with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump([x, y], f)


>>> with open('text.txt') as f:
    x, y = pickle.load(f)


>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
True
```

But then you might as well just pickle one list!

Comment: Thanks! So the real case is that I got a list, some elements are distinct and some are identical and are just difference names for the same object. If I still want the latter kind to share the same reference, should I compare them, if the objects they refer to are identical then let `x = y`? Or is there some more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: If you just `pickle` the whole list, indices that reference the same object will still reference the same objects after unpickling. There's no need to unpack to separate names then put those names in a container and pickle that.